# how to add a find a year in path file name using re.findall

Tags: python, regex, csv

Using re.findall to find a digits in multiple path files using a loop. However some the files contain other digits or doesn't contain a '20' infant of them. wondering how to just get the files corresponding year e.g. 2014 or 2020.

Here is some examples of the files names:

```
ts20individual25countaveragemedianbypostcode.csv
taxstats2016individual28countaveragemedianbypostcode.csv
```

I would then like to append it to a list

```
dfyear = []

for f in csv_files:
      
    # read the csv file
    df = pd.read_csv(f)
    
    x = [int(s) for s in re.findall(r'[\d]+', f)]
    dfyear.append(x)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"... some the files contain other digits or doesn't contain a '20' infant of them. wondering how to just get the files corresponding year e.g. 2014 or 2020. ..."*

It appears the year value is prefixed by either *"ts"* or *"taxstats"*, so I'd utilize this.

```
(?:ts|taxstats)20\d*
```

Here is an example, where *m* is the list of matching values.

```java
import re
f = ['ts20individual25countaveragemedianbypostcode.csv',
     'taxstats2016individual28countaveragemedianbypostcode.csv']
m = [x for x in f if re.search(r'(?:ts|taxstats)20\d*', x)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If all years start with a `20` and continue with two more digits you could use the regex

```
'20\d{2}'
```

Or - should you also want years starting with `19`

```
'(19|20)\d{2}'
```

Comment: some filenames do not contain start with '20' and have other digits involved such as :  'ts20individual25countaveragemedianbypostcode.csv'

Comment: @SUPERREDPANDA In you example what would be your required result? Always the first number is the year? because I see two numbers, both could be valid years (2020 and 2025). How is a "year number" defined for you?

Comment: 2020 always the first year. The files range from 2014 to 2020.

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehensions to progressively filter and map the filenames:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
import re

# current year cannot be exceeded
year = datetime.now().year - 2000

# keep all 2 and 4 digit groups which might be years
matches = [list(map(int, re.findall("((?:20)?\d{2})", x))) for x in files]

# keep 2-digits years lower or equal to current year and 4-digits years
years = [list(filter(lambda x: (x<= year) or (x>=2000), match)) for match in matches]
years = [x[0]+2000 if x[0]<2000 else x[0] for x in years]
```

Which results in:

```
print(matches)
[[20, 25], [2016, 28]]

print(years)
[2020, 2016]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = ['ts20individual25countaveragemedianbypostcode.csv',
'taxstats2016individual28countaveragemedianbypostcode.csv']

years = []
for f in lst:
    matches = re.search(r'\d{2}|\d{4}(?=individual)', f)
    if matches:
        year = matches.group(0)
        if len(year) == 2:
            year = '20' + year
            years.append(year)
        else:
            years.append(year)
       

print(years)

['2020', '2016']
```